# Logic inside a basic class method not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, function, class, oop, if-statement

Fooling around with Classes trying to understand them better and I've found myself stuck with what should otherwise be extremely basic.

The code below is basically just a class extending another and me trying them out.
My issue has to do specifically with the logic within the Animal method `danger(dangerLvl)`.

The way it's written just below works as expected:

```
class Animal {
    constructor(name, age, dangerLvl) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.dangerLvl = dangerLvl;
    }
    danger(dangerLvl) {
        if (dangerLvl != 0) {
            return `${this.name} is dangerous!`
        } else {
            return `${this.name} is docile :)`
        }
    }
}

class Feline extends Animal {
    hiss() {
        return `${this.name} hisses threateningly!`
    }
}

const sissi = new Feline("Sissi", 5, 1);

sissi.danger();
// returns "Sissi is dangerous!"
```

What I don't get is the behavior of the method `danger(dangerLvl)` when written like this:

```
    danger(dangerLvl) {
        if (dangerLvl >= 1) {
            return `${this.name} is dangerous!`
        } else {
            return `${this.name} is docile :)`
        }
    }

const sissi = new Feline("Sissi", 5, 1);

sissi.danger();
// returns "Sissi is docile :)" <===== which is NOT expected. This is what I don't get.
```

Not exactly sure how I've managed to get to a point where I somewhat get async functions, callbacks and prototypes but can't figure out something as basic as this. Quite frustrating to say the least.

In my mind I should even be able to write it this way but clearly I'm missing something...

```
    danger(dangerLvl) {
        if (dangerLvl >= 1) {
            return `${this.name} is dangerous!`
        }
        return `${this.name} is docile :)`
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try printing dangerLvl right before the comparison happens.

Comment: dangerLvl is undefined. The animal will always be dangerous

Comment: You didn't pass the argument.... And `undefined >= 1` evaluates to false. The function should actually not take an argument at all, and you should use the member with the same name.

Comment: // returns "Sissi is dangerous!", // returns "Sissi is docile :)" Your own print statments are not matching. Since dangerLvl is being used from an argument, it will always be undefined. Try to use `this.dangerLvl` instead

Comment: Thank you all, these basic mistakes have me shaking my head in disappointment*. Appreciate the handholding folks.

Comment: @AmirSaleem kindly, could you post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as an accepted answer? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not passing `dangerLvl` as an argument, it is undefined. If you want to access the `dangerLvl` class member you need to use `this`. Here is an example

```js
class Animal {
    constructor(name, age, dangerLvl) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.dangerLvl = dangerLvl;
    }
    danger() {
        if (this.dangerLvl != 0) {
            return `${this.name} is dangerous!`
        } else {
            return `${this.name} is docile :)`
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand at all why you use the **dangerLvl** as argument of **Animal.prototype.danger** function if you have it on that context, if you don't define the argument it will be passed as undefined and the condition is getting else because `undefined >= 1` is false.

```js
class Animal {
    constructor(name, age, dangerLvl) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.dangerLvl = dangerLvl;
    }
    danger(){
        
        console.log(this.dangerLvl);
    
        if (this.dangerLvl >= 1) {
            return `${this.name} is dangerous!`
        } else {
            return `${this.name} is docile :)`
        }
    }
}

class Feline extends Animal {
    
    hiss() {
        return `${this.name} hisses threateningly!`
    }
}

const sissi = new Feline("Sissi", 5, 1);

console.log(sissi.danger()); //Sissi is dangerous


const sissi2 = new Feline("Rabbit", 5, undefined);

console.log(sissi2.danger()); //Rabbit is docile :)
```